# Configure Cipher Suites on OS X iOS

Tags: ios, macos, ssl, encryption

I need disable some cipher suites which are not secure enough for my application.  I need configure enabled cipher suites when using `NSURLSession` or `CFNetwork` (socket used for webSocket connection).

I can see that there is [such API for `SSLContex`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Reference/secureTransportRef/) but I've found nothing for higher level API (`NSURLSession` or `CFNetwork`).
I also don't see that `SSLContex` could be set/get for `NSURLSession` or `CFNetwork` (this would solve the problem).